# AS3: Alert event firing with no input

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I have an alert that pops up when a user clicks on a delete button. However, when the alert is created, it fires the Yes function despite no user input.

Obviously, with a delete button this is bad.

```
        protected function handleDelete(event:Event): void {
            showAlert();
        }

        private function showAlert():void{
            Alert.yesLabel = "Delete";
            Alert.noLabel = "Cancel";
            Alert.show("Are you sure you want to delete this?", "Confirm Delete", Alert.YES|Alert.CANCEL, this, delete(), null, Alert.CANCEL);
        }
```

Not sure why, but delete() fires when the alert is created, no matter the input from the user.

Alert is the Flex default alert, no overrides or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete()` shall be without `()` because you want to pass a reference to it, not to call it and pass return value.

Comment: I tried that and got ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on components.dialogs::DeleteDialog/delete(). Expected 0, got 1.

         I added e:Event as a parameter and now it runs delete() no matter the button I push.

Comment: That's because it's not expecting an event handler, just a 0-arg callback function. Just remove `event:Event` from the method definition.

Comment: I get an argument mismatch if I remove it

Comment: It must accept CloseEvent, `detail` field will contain code of the button that was selected. You shall compare it with Alert.YES and only then execute deletion.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see where I went wrong. I never checked if I had pushed yes or cancel. Thanks